# Elisp for applying command to only the selected region

Tags: region, interactive

Say, I have some code like this:

```
(defun some-function ()
  (interactive)
  ;; do something
  )
```

Now I want `some-function` to operate only on the selected region in
the buffer ? How can I do that ? Also, can there be two separate code
path for doing something if I have selected some region and doing
something else If I haven't selected.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```el
(defun some-function (beginning end)
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (message "The region is active, and is from %d to %d" beginning end)
    (message "The region is still there (from % d to %d), but it is inactive" 
             beginning end)))
```

The use of `(interactive "r")` means that the parameters `beginning` and `end` will automatically receive the values of the region beginning and the region end, respectively, when the function is invoked. (You can also get those values anytime using the functions `region-beginning` and `region-end`, respectively.)

The region is always present (if there is a mark in the current buffer), but you might not think it is.  The region is **active** when it is highlighted (text is selected). You can test whether the region is active using predicate `region-active-p`.  But the better test is usually `use-region-p`, because (by default) it returns true (non-`nil`) only when the region is both active and nonempty (point and mark are different).

Originally, there was no highlighting of the region.  And for a long time, even though highlighting was available, it was not the default behavior.  For highlighting to occur, you must have `transient-mark-mode` turned on (or turned on at least temporarily). By default, `transient-mark-mode` is turned on in recent Emacs versions.

It's helpful to look at the definition of predicate `use-region-p`:

```el
(defun use-region-p ()
  (and (region-active-p)
       (or use-empty-active-region
           (> (region-end) (region-beginning)))))
```

`use-empty-active-region` is a user option, whose default value is `nil` (false), meaning that by default `use-region-p` will not return true if the region is empty.  In that case, for it to return true, the end of the region must be greater than the beginning (the behavior I described above).

And if we look at the definition of `region-active-p`:

```el
(defun region-active-p ()
  (and transient-mark-mode
       mark-active
       (mark)))
```

We see that it returns true (non-`nil`) when all of these are true:

- `transient-mark-mode` is turned on.
- The mark is active (`mark-active`).
- There is a mark in the current buffer.

The mark being active is really what the region being active is all about.  When it is active, assuming that `transient-mark-mode` is on and there is a mark in the current buffer, the region is highlighted.

Comment: AFAICS if mark is set to point, i.e. region has not extend, mark-active is nil. So mark-active and transient-mark-mode are the only things adding value in these fairly redundant functions.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler: Nope. `C-SPC` `M-: mark-active` => t. You can definitely have an empty region that is nevertheless active.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Still think mark-active and  region-active-p --defined as extend greater zero-- should be all needed.

Comment: @Drew, I believe there's a typo in: ", whose default value is nil (true)," . It should probably read ",whose default is nil (false)" or something like that since non-nil corresponds to true.

Comment: @PRouleau: Good catch; thx. (Yup, `nil` means false.) Fixed.