# Adjust end index in selected region

Tags: debugging, numbers

Following the advice given [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12334/elisp-for-applying-command-to-only-the-selected-region?rq=1), I  wrote the following code  to enclose the text selection in phpbb italics tags :

```
(defun wrap-in-phpbb-italics-tag (b e)
  "does what its name says."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
      (goto-char b)
      (insert (format "[i]"))
      (goto-char e)
      (insert (format "[/i]"))))
```

This code almost does  what I want : the left tag is positioned correctly but the right tag is three characters too early.
Thus, if the selected goes `Adjust end index in selected region`, the result will be `[i]Adjust end index in selected reg[/i]ion`.

I tried to fix it as follows, replacing the `(e)` with `(e+3)` :

```
(defun wrap-in-phpbb-italics-tag (b e)
  "does what its name says."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
      (goto-char b)
      (insert (format "[i]"))
      (goto-char (e+3))
      (insert (format "[/i]"))))
```

But with this new code, the right tag simply disappears. What is going on here ? How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains an error: `(e+3)`, it should be `(+ e 3)`. When you run your command, Emacs will report the following error message in Echo Area and the `*Messages*` buffer

> goto-char: Symbol's function definition is void: e+3

Alternatively, you can insert at the end then at the beginning, so you don't need to `+3` since `b` isn't moved at all.

```
(defun wrap-in-phpbb-italics-tag (b e)
  "does what its name says."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char e)
    (insert "[/i]")
    (goto-char b)
    (insert "[i]")))
```

Comment: exactly the answer I needed, containing both the solution and an explanation on every detail. Thank you very much